# I have problem with my border in CSS after I installing tailwind/flowbite

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css, flowbite

I have a little problem with tailwind and flowbite

I made inputs to be able to connect and I applied a "border-buttom 1px solid black" to have only one bar at the bottom of the input, but I installed after tailwind and flowbite and now my border doesn't work anymore and I see with the dev tools that some style was added (see screenshot) is it related to tailwind/flowbite ? If yes how to deactivate its default settings ?

[image: Screenshot]

I have searched all my code, try to change the css by adding "border: 0" etc... But nothing to do, I do not understand, I even search on Google but nothing...

Comment: at the end it says `--tw-shadow` so I assume it's tailwind. You could add another class (`my-inputs`) to the inputs, and set  border to `border: none!important`, `border-bottom: 1px solid black !important` inside the css  Don't know if it's none or unset on the border.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding the class `border-b` to the input instead of adding the property `border-bottom`.